# Simple Harmonic System Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Question:

[image]

Equations:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding what a "solution" to equation 6 refers to? What are the implications of including gravity in the equation?

Answer (score 0):

$Mg$ is a constant so only changes the equilibrium position, not the angular frequency. Equation 6 can be rearranged to give

$$\frac{d^2y}{dy^2}=-\frac{k}{M}(y+L_0+\frac{Mg}{k})$$

This makes the new equilibrium position $L_0+\frac{Mg}{k}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically this is a differential equation. But, a solution is any function that you write down and replace $y(t)$ with $guess(t)$ and $y(t)_{tt}$ with $guess(t)_{tt}$, and the equality will still hold.

The implication of including gravity is mathematically making it $F(y,y_{tt})=const \neq 0$ instead of having a homogeneous and boring  $F(y,y_{tt})=0$. In this case you just need to add it to your guessed or calculated solution to the homogenous equation and it will be true. And it will also be a general solution, so cheating works.

Answer (score 0):

It means does the solution of equation (5) satisfy eq (6)? You can check it by putting the solution in equation. As for your next question,it has just shifted the equilibrium point  of the system around which your particle oscillated. You can gain more if you can solve the differential equation.